# Photoshop CC: How to set default transform reference point to top left?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, transform

I work on UI projects in Photoshop CC and need to be able to set default transform reference point to top left to make it easier for me to precisely position elements. It always keeps defaulting to center, which means every single time I want to reposition an element I have to click on the top left point. The loss in efficiency pains me...Is there a way to set the default reference point to top left?

[image]

Comment: I do not believe you can. This question is better suited to SuperUser.com